# Notation of an LTI system consisting of LTI filters

Tags: filters, linear-systems, z-transform

I would like to find a reference for two notations of an LTI system consisting of LTI filters. In z-domain, the LTI system is given by

$$
 \mathbf{y}(z) = \mathbf{C}(z) \mathbf{s}(z) + \mathbf{D}(z) \mathbf{x}(z) \\
 \mathbf{s}(z) = \mathbf{A}(z) \mathbf{s}(z) + \mathbf{B}(z) \mathbf{x}(z) ,
$$
where $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ are the input and output of the system, respectively and $\mathbf{s}$ is the system state. The matrices $\mathbf{A}$, $\mathbf{B}$, $\mathbf{C}$ and $\mathbf{D}$ constist of LTI filters, e.g., 
$$
A_{ij}(z) = \frac{b_0 + b_1 z^{-1} + \dots + b_k z^{-k}}{a_0 + a_1 z^{-1} + \dots + a_k z^{-k}}.
$$
Now, each LTI filter can be represented by its impulse response in time domain. Let the matrices $\mathbf{A'}(n)$, $\mathbf{B'}(n)$, $\mathbf{C'}(n)$ and $\mathbf{D'}(n)$ with $n$ indicating time such that e.g.
$$
A'_{ij} = [a'_0, a'_1, a'_2, \dots ] 
$$
is the impulse response of the LTI filter $A_{ij}(z)$.

Is it then possible to rewrite the whole LTI system in time-domain as
$$
 \mathbf{y}(n) = (\mathbf{C} \ast \mathbf{s})(n) + (\mathbf{D} \ast \mathbf{x})(n) \\
 \mathbf{s}(n) = (\mathbf{A} \ast \mathbf{s})(n) + (\mathbf{B} \ast \mathbf{x})(n) ,
$$
where $\ast$ denotes the convolution operation. I would especially appreciate any reference to literature / text books where this representation is discussed.

An one-dimensional example:
The state-transition matrix may be a (time-invariant) one-pole filter, e.g., $\mathbf{A}(z) = \frac{b_0}{1 - a_1 z^{-1}}$. The corresponding time-domain $\mathbf{A}'(n)$ is the impulse response of this one-pole filter.

Comment: Welcome to SP.SE!  It's not usual for the system matrices ($\mathbf{A}$, $\mathbf{B}$, $\mathbf{C}$ and $\mathbf{D}$) to be functions of time... because that means the system you're representing is not time-invariant. Can you give an example of where that notation is used?

Comment: @PeterK. : Thank you very much for your welcome! Please note that the system matrices are not time-variant, although the time-domain notation is somehow ambiguous. I add an example to hopefully clarify.

Comment: Hmm. Taking the $z$-transform of $\mathbf{A}$ suggests that it is time varying... otherwise the $z$-transform of $\mathbf{A}$ is $\mathbf{A}$. See [this page for example.](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Control_Systems/State-Space_Equations#State-Space_Equations)

Comment: @PeterK. Ok, this needs some clarification. We can agree that the one-pole filter above is time-invariant (it is a classic LTI filter)? Hence, the impulse response of the one-pole filter is time-invariant as well, right?

Comment: @PeterK. In contrast, what I would call a time-variant filter is when the values of the impulse response are changing over time as in your linked example.

Comment: @PeterK. : See for example the [transfer function matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_function_matrix)

Comment: If $\mathbf{A}(z) = \frac{b_0}{1 - a_zz^{-1}}$ and $\mathbf{A}(z)$ is the state transition matrix, then the system it is part of is time varying.

Comment: The link you give does not decompose $G(s)$ into a state space equation.

Comment: @PeterK. : Right, this may be a better [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-loop_transfer_function) . In the derivation below, the system is stated in state-space form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58834/discussion-between-peter-k-and-sebastian-schlecht).

Answer (score 1):

As I've said in chat, I do not believe the system
$$
 \mathbf{y}(z) = \mathbf{C}(z) \mathbf{s}(z) + \mathbf{D}(z) \mathbf{x}(z) \\
 \mathbf{s}(z) = \mathbf{A}(z) \mathbf{s}(z) + \mathbf{B}(z) \mathbf{x}(z) ,
$$
with the matrices time-varying is an LTI system.

That means, I don't think we can answer your question.

If the matrices are not functions of $z$ then you can write the transfer function as:
$$
\mathbf{y}(z)/\mathbf{x}(z) = \mathbf{C}(zI - \mathbf{A})^{-1} \mathbf{B} + \mathbf{D}
$$
but it's not clear to me if this equation is valid if the matrices are time-varying / $z$-transforms.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I cannot help to go on thinking that we talk about different ideas of time-varying. I need to find a more compelling example and let you know.

Comment: @SebastianSchlecht Please do! We are obviously talking at cross-purposes, so any examples would be helpful to figure out what's happening.